# Replace Array.ConvertAll in NetCore 1.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

My current code is using `Array.ConvertAll`, which I need to migrate to net core 1.0. How to migrate it to work in Net core.

Can we use `foreach` statement with custom conversion code to handle the conversion?
But I don't know how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of

```cs
int[] array1 = ...
string[] array2 = Array.ConvertAll(array1, element => element.ToString());
```

You could use Linq:

```cs
int[] array1 = ...
string[] array2 = array1.Select(element => element.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if you upgrade to latest .NET Core 1.0 official release (forget about all previous testing bits), you can use this method in `System.Runtime` package,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.array#System_Array_ConvertAll__2___0___System_Converter___0___1__

Comment: Hi Li, I upgrate project to core 1.0 and System.Runtime package is also installed. But couldn't fime ConvertAll.